# How to replace the aptana studio find/replace dialogue by eclipse find/replace dialogue ?

Tags: eclipse, aptana

I am using Aptana studio plugin on Eclipse Juno.

I love the features Aptana studio offers but I do not like the find and replace dialogue by Aptana.

I want to replace it by the default one in Eclipse.

Is it possible and if so how?

Comment: Could you please post a snapshot of the Aptana Studio ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Aptana Studio's preferences, goto `Aptana Studio -> Find Bar` and **uncheck** `Use custom find bar on Aptana editors` like so :

[image]

After that, if you press Ctrl + F you should get the normal eclipse Find/Replace search dialogue like so :

[image]

Comment: The Aptana Studio built-in find bar is such a useless feature that it should be removed altogether and revert to the regular eclipse find/replace instead.